# Adding a Web Domain on Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, ip-address, domain-name

I recently purchased a Windows Server 2008 server, Our company will be using it as a Web Server.  I have set the web site up in IIS 7.0 and I can accsess it by typing http://10.1.1.8 on the computers within the network.

When I try to accsess it through the net on other computers it doesnt seem to work, But most important, How do I set up a web domain such as (www.example.com) ??

Many Thanks,
             Oliver

Answer (score 2):

It has a private internet address.  Presumably your company also has a real, assign internet address space.  If you want to access if from outside your company, you need to give the system an address in the official address space.  Associate that address with the name of the web site (www.yourcompany.com) and all will be taken care of.

All addresses in the 10.x.x.x and 192.168.x.x ranges are private addresses inaccessible from other networks.  See assigned address spaces [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/), particularly the notes at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming: 
 - you have an internet connection with a fixed ip address
 - your internet connection passes through some sort of router/firewall
 - the registrar that provided your domain name provides dns hosting

1. Setup the TCP/IP settings for your web server to assign it a fixed internal IP address (i.e. do not use DHCP)
2. Configure your firewall to route all HTTP traffic (see the documentation for your particular router / firewall) to the internal IP address setup in step 1.
3. In the administration for your domain name with your registrar, add two dns records (one for .yourdomain.com and *.yourdomain.com that point to the external fixed IP address provided for your internet connection.